# In java properties file itself can we concatenate two or more than two variables together?

Tags: string-concatenation, properties-file

I have gateway.properties file and it has following content:

```
current.path=c:/projects/sdk/
log.path=storage/logs
```

Here, in this file:

1. Either, I want to add third variable which is `current.log.path` and its value must be:

   ```
   current.log.path=current.path + log.path
   ```
2. Or, I want to append string to `current.path` variable as below:

   ```
   current.path=current.path+log.path
   ```

I have a situation that I can't do this concatenation/append job in my Java file. In Java its pretty simple but I have no idea how to do within file itself.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in mechanism to have something like variables in a property file. You could try [Apache Commons Configuration](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_basicfeatures.html#Variable_Interpolation). I think it is what you are looking for.